# ARM GCC linker script for .data section initialization on start-up in RAM

Tags: gcc, linker, arm, embedded, stm32

Although my question concerns compilation and linking with ARM GCC for STM32, it's more directly related to the correct writing of the linker script for GCC.

I have the following linker script for STM32:

```
MEMORY
{
  CCMSRAM (xrw) : ORIGIN = 0x10000000,   LENGTH = 32K
  RAM     (xrw) : ORIGIN = 0x20000000,   LENGTH = 128K
  ROM     (rx)  : ORIGIN = 0x08000000,   LENGTH = 512K
}

/* Sections */
SECTIONS
{

...

  .init_array :
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__init_array_start = .);
    KEEP (*(SORT(.init_array.*)))
    KEEP (*(.init_array*))
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__init_array_end = .);
    . = ALIGN(4);
  } >ROM

...

  /* Used by the startup to initialize data */
  _sidata = LOADADDR(.data);

  /* Initialized data sections into "RAM" Ram type memory */
  .data : 
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    _sdata = .;        /* create a global symbol at data start */
    *(.data)           /* .data sections */
    *(.data*)          /* .data* sections */

    . = ALIGN(4);
    _edata = .;        /* define a global symbol at data end */
    
  } >RAM AT> ROM

...

}
```

Here `_sidata` and `.data` are important for what I want to achieve. Since STM32 microcontrollers have separate Flash memory, which contains the program code, and separate RAM, which contains the variable, this standard linker script does the following:

1. Initialized variables are initially contained in the code and programmed into Flash memory. This is specified in the linker script using `>RAM AT> ROM`. They are located in Flash memory starting from the `_sidata` address.
2. When the controller starts, the start-up code copies variables from Flash memory starting from the `_sidata` address to RAM to the `_sdata` address (the start of the `.data` area).
3. After that there is a transition to `main()`.
   Everything is as expected.

**What I want to achieve:** the same behavior, but so that all the program and data are located in RAM, and the initialization of variables on start-up is also done every time the same way.

So, in essence, I want to have two equal-sized memory areas with the variables initial values in `_sidata`  area, while having another equal-sized `.data` area. And at each start, the start-up code also copies the values from `_sidata` to `_sdata` (the start of the `.data` area), restoring the initial values, which may have changed since the previous program execution.

If I change this line in ld scrip `>RAM AT> ROM` to `>RAM` (or even to `>RAM AT> RAM`), then the linker makes addresses of `_sidata` and `_sdata` equal, so there is only one area with initial variable values, and copying the values ​​before executing the main program does actually nothing, since this rewriting to the same place. On the next execution initial values have already been lost.

I tried to look for the answer in examples and manuals, but I didn’t find the answer I needed. How should I change the ld script to get the desired result?

Comment: What you're trying to achieve sounds like default behavior that you already described. What exactly in what you're trying to achieve, is different from default way that it's done by default? Default startup code before main does 100% what you want, no? If that's not the case, you will have to find better words to describe what you want. Maybe draw an illustration.

Comment: The linker traditionally supplied together with gcc binaries is technically part of binutils which a different project than gcc. Nonetheless, [here](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Output-Section-LMA.html) is (maybe relevant portion of) its manual. LMA address is probably evaluated *before* the section is populated, so probably the easiest way is to assign it a fixed address, e.g. half the RAM. Now *why* do you want to do this, and what are all the consequences and ramifications, I leave it to you...

Comment: @Ilya If I change the attribute of all sections to ">RAM" (instead of ">ROM" and ">RAM AT> ROM", including ".data"), the linker sets the same address for "_sidata=LOADADDR(.data)" and "_sdata". These two pointers are equal, and physically point to the same memory location. In this case, copying doesn't make sense, because the data is copied to itself, i.e. 0x2000 => 0x2000. It is clear that after the restart, all initial values of the variables will be lost. I want these two pointers not to be equal, there to be two areas, and after the restart the initial values of the variables are restored.

Comment: @wek Yes, I read this section of the documentation, but I couldn't figure out how to specifically do what I want. Yes, I can set a specific address for this section, or change the start-up code so that it makes another copy and then restores it etc. But these are workarounds and dirty hacks. I think there should be a way to do this through an ld script, since this is its default behavior if there are two memory sections. I just don't know how to write this correctly.

Comment: You have just repeated yourself with the same words and provided zero additional information. I still fail to understand how what you want to achieve differs from default compilation & linking in literally any preconfigured IDE. Startup code runs every time your MCU restarts by default, it will repopulate everything by default every time. If you want code and data bundled together in RAM, maybe you should use position independent code then?

Comment: Please, draw a good illustration with memory space, where you want to place all the stuff, and how it happens right now. I think it would simplify understanding of what actually happens and what you want to achieve.

Comment: For example, what confuses me is, your quote: What I want to achieve: the same behavior, but so that all the program and data are located in RAM, and the initialization of variables on start-up is also done every time the same way. - Doesn't the same startup code run every time anyway?

Comment: @Ilya The start-up code run every time anyway, but results are different, if code is in ROM or in RAM. When it runs from ROM, every time on Reset you have the same initial values of variables. When it runs from RAM, you have correct initial values of variables only for the first run. After any further reset values can be different, because linker links two pointer to one address, and there is really no array of variables with initial values in RAM. They change during program execution. It happens for the reasons, described above.

Comment: So, you want a linker to point to ROM, not RAM, for the initial values. Always. But you have code in RAM. I'm very much leaning to compiling it as position-independent code then, where .data will be referenced through program counter + offset, and init values will be baked into the code (which is in RAM). Is there a reason you can't try PIC?

Comment: X-Y problem.  Having no sense at all

Answer (score -1):

There are two options here.

- you want to re-initialize the global variables to boot time values.
- you want to duplicate flash execution (as close as possible) with direct execution from RAM (using a development tool).

---

For the 2nd case,

You need to duplicate the data **output** section.  It might be possible to use `VMA` and `LMA` for this task (stanza `>AT`), but simpler is to just duplicate things.

You can duplicate the sections following the methods in [duplicate sections in elf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31125217/how-to-make-duplicate-sections-in-elf-file).

`_sidata` is just a variable name.  If you want both flash (for initial boot) and re-initialize at runtime, you can just use the flash copy.  This is more robust as the flash is much more difficult to overwrite.  It seems like it would fulfill what you want?

The use case I see for your request is to keep code similar for a JTAG download direct to RAM.

[This answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8458084/align-in-linker-scripts/72942905#72942905) gives alternate assembler to the absolute horrible STM32 supplied copying code.  It relies on properly aligned sections.  You can use linker assertions in production code to check at build time. Similar improvements can be made to the zeroing code.  This can be important if time to functionality is a concern.

For the 1st case, there is no need to modify the linker file.

The code for re-initialing data can be converted to a routine.  This also simplifies the startup code and is completely safe if only leaf calls are made so only `lr` is used.  For example,

```
data_reinit:
ldr r0, =_sidata
/* ...*/
2: bx lr    /* exit */
```

Ie, just add a label and a return.  The routine is meant to be ABI compatible.  This will re-initialize RAM data from the flash copy, given the assembler in the other answer with the conversion to a routine.

It can be called from 'C' as `extern data_reinit(void);` and then just `data_reinit();`.  Also,  the other link has methods do code the whole thing in 'C'.

```
extern uint32_t _sidata, _sdata, _edata;
uint32_t *src = &_sidata;
uint32_t  *dst = &_sdata;
/* ROM has data at end of text; copy it.  */
while (dst < &_edata)
  *dst++ = *src++;
```

Note that the STM32 code generations and releases do not use the `.ALIGN()` properly.  I explain [this here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58902628/what-are-data-segment-initializers/71849963#71849963).  Ie, an internal `. = ALIGN(XX);` is useless as an internal '.' updates are relative to the section start.  So '.' is zero here and the `ALIGN(XX)` is a no-op.  You can align external to a section, or use the `ALIGN(XX)` after a colon in the section leader to create an absolute alignment (meaning sections alignment relative to each other).  Internal alignments are meant for alignments within the section (inside the curly brackets).

Comment: The section flags should be inherited from the input sections.

Comment: "It relies on properly aligned sections." - linker section definitions guaratee it (`ALIGN(4)`).

Comment: @gulp  Yes, but if someone modifies the linker script to remove it, the code will break as it will load an unaligned address.  The point is that there is no truth between a linker script and assembler.  You can write assertions in the linker script as a double check that the section is aligned.  It is wrong that I wrote assembler assertions.  It can only be done (easily) in a linker script.

Comment: @artlessnoise Thanks for answer. Initially values were: ".init_array 0x20001628(addr) 0x4(size)" & ".data 0x20001630 0x60"
I tried the code you suggested with "_sidata = .; *(.data) *(.data*)" in ".init_data" section.
Unfortunately, the result is actually not as expected. Now ".init_array 0x20001628 0x64", and ".data 0x20001690 0x0". So, in fact, the initial data is now simply in ".init_array", the size of ".data" is 0, and the start-up code copies "_sidata" to ".bss", the same address as ".data" now (although after it writes 0s there). I would like ".data" to be at least sized appropriately

Comment: @artlessnoise I added my initial ".init_array" section code to the question.

Comment: @cyclone125  You are correct.  I updated my answer.  I forgot that ld only uses an input section once (which is a good rule for many other cases).